# Has any relevant American politician ever publicly admitted that the Gulf of Tonkin incident was a lie?

Tags: united-states, armed-conflict, history, war-crime, vietnam

During an interview ([video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdjv1j0sOyk)) celebrity and former Governor of Minnesota [Jesse Ventura](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesse_Ventura) said that "they" were admitting that [the Gulf of Tonkin incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_of_Tonkin_incident) was a lie.

There are somewhat credible private remarks [by president Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_B._Johnson):

> In 1965, President Johnson commented privately: "For all I know, our navy was shooting at whales out there."

And a newly [released tape acknowledged](https://www.nytimes.com/2001/11/06/us/new-tapes-indicate-johnson-doubted-attack-in-tonkin-gulf.html?mcubz=0) by the New York Times:

> In 1995, retired Vietnamese Defence Minister, Võ Nguyên Giáp, meeting with former Secretary McNamara, denied that Vietnamese gunboats had attacked American destroyers on August 4, while admitting to the attack on August 2. A taped conversation of a meeting several weeks after passage of the Gulf of Tonkin Resolution was released in 2001, revealing that McNamara expressed doubts to President Johnson that the attack had even occurred...

**Are there any American politicians who actually admitted it was a lie (or false flag operation) in order to prevent Communism spreading in Asia or similar reason?**

Comment: A mistake is different than a lie. Someone in the know claiming there was irrefutable evidence of a NV attack, now that would be a lie. Was Johnson lying, or merely not mentioning that there were conflicting reports about whether an attack had occurred? Some might reasonably call Johnson's statement a lie.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ron Paul spoke about the Gulf of Tonkin incident and referred to it as a metaphor for a ruse to start a war with Iran while speaking to Congress about the perils of the Iraq war.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRB3UBz1KEQ